# Word to say father of twins

Tags: word-request

Is there any word or phrase to call a man, whose wife has given birth to twin children ?

I need to text my friends about one of us, who just became father of twins. How can I describe the party thought, such as *Let us wish him by joining the pleasure twin fatherhood !!!*

Comment: There is no such single word in English. Is there one in any natural language? That would be interesting! FYI, when we're joking around, native English speakers sometimes refer to the twins themselves as "double trouble" (because kids are often *trouble* to their parents, since they're twins, there're two of them, or "double the standard amount of trouble" [one child], but mostly because the phrase rhymes, and is cute).

Comment: good point @DanBron I am curious to know as well! I don't think in any language there's a special word for it!

Comment: Okay, @DanBron @Maulik, what about th word I mentioned here, `twin fatherhood`?

Comment: @MaulikV, Yeah, may be twin children birth is anamoly, still. Gotta check with anthropology on past histories of human race to have twin births :)

Comment: @nmxprime That's not *a word*, that's *two words*. And if you're willing to accept two words, I vote for "**double daddy**"!

Comment: "Twin fatherhood" (suggested in your question) is pretty good, I think. If these are his first children, you could also say "new dad times two" – but that's hardly an established phrase.

Comment: Well, to say that no language has a single word for this idea would require that you know every language in the world.

Comment: @nmxprime "Past histories of human race" I don't think twins are a recent invention. They've certainly been around for a long time. The Bible mentions twins -- Jacob and Esau -- I'd have to look it up but I think they're something like 2000 BC. And Roman writers say that the founders of Rome, Romulus and Remus, were twins. I think Rome was founded 743 BC if I recall correctly. And Greek mythology mentions the twins Castor and Pollux. Etc.

Comment: @Jay, amazing explanation, very appriciatable. Thanks Jay..

Comment: We call the father of twins "Isabarongo* and mother of twins "Nyinabarongo" #Runyoro/Rutoro language.

Comment: Call him “Twin Father” to suit the Luganda expression “Ssalongo”.

Comment: The father of twins is called " Salongo" while the mother is called "Nalongo" in many of the native languages in Uganda.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Dan Bron says, there is no single word in English that means "father of twins". I don't know any more concise way to say it than to say "father of twins".

"Twin fatherhood" is possible, and if you're talking specifically to or about this person would presumably be understood. But note that "twin" can be used generally to mean two of the same thing, of any thing. Like, "A twin-engine airplane" means an airplane with two engines; we took about a car with two exhaust pipes having "twin exhausts"; etc. So "twin fatherhood" could refer to two men who are both fathers, as opposed to one man having twins.

BTW your proposed sentence, "Let us wish him by joining the pleasure twin fatherhood", has several grammar errors. "By joining" what? I think you mean we should join together in making this wish, but the sentence leaves this dangling. Then, what are you wishing? I take it you mean that you wish him "the pleasure", but it reads very oddly having "by joining" in the middle. And finally, assuming you go with "twin fatherhood", you need to say "OF twin fatherhood".

And finally, you're not really wishing for him to have this pleasure, because -- assuming that it's a pleasure! -- he already has it. You're congratulating him on it. I suppose you might be wishing that it will be a pleasure and not a burden.

So I think what you want to say is more like, "Let us join in congratulating him on the pleasure of twin fatherhood", or I'd say, "Let us join in congratulating him on becoming the father of twins".

Answer (score 2):

*Father/mother of twins*, this **is** the phrase used in (American) English. This extends to *brother/sister of twins*. While the phrase *twin brothers/sisters/sons* or *twin brother and sister/son and daughter* are used. This usage extends to *father/mother of triplets, quadruplets/quintuplets/etc, ad infinitum*. (well maybe not *ad infinitum*).

Just one [example](http://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation-now/2015/04/14/texas-first-all-girl-quintuplets-born-united-states/25792169/):

> A Houston couple became **the parents of** the United States' first ever **all-girl quintuplets**

As far as a congratulatory note, you could use "Let us all congratulate Tom on his *double daddyhood*"